# Reactjs and nodejs login, registration module

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs

I want to build an app using reactjs in frontend and nodejs or java as backend. does anyone can provide any help. please share your references links.

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest ways to implement a user authentication system in React and Node is with [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/). Passport.js also has a ton of different strategies you can use in addition to normal local  authentication. There are a bunch of great free resources that will guide you on how to set this up if you search for it. Here are a few:

- [Node.js Authentication using Passport.js](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-authentication-passport-js/)
- [React Passport Example Application](https://github.com/shouheiyamauchi/react-passport-example)